# Exporting module declaration in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings

I want to extend some of the properties in MUI button component. So I am doing like this,

```
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
    interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
        dashed: true;
    }

    interface ButtonPropsSizeOverrides {
        extraLarge: true
    }
}
```

After doing this, when I am using `Button` from MUI, I am getting variant as `dashed` and size as `extraLarge` as one of the options.

But now I want to export this button as another package (for eg name as MyMUIComponents). When I am using button from `MyMUIComponents` package, I can't see these additional properties as added above.

I know it will be something related to ambient declaration but not getting exactly how?

How can I achieve it?
Can someone please guide me?